# How to print both to stdout and file in C

Tags: c, file-io

I read this topic, but his problem maybe different from mine
[Writing to both stdout & a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661070/writing-to-both-stdout-a-file)

I want to write a function, that function need to print out to both stdout and a file. My C program gets user input by scanf.

I intend to write a function like printf but I don't really know how:

I tried this, but it only can work with "pure" string, can't convert %d, %.*lf (my print function only need two conversions)

```
void dupPrint(FILE *fp,char *string)
{
    printf("%s",string);
    fprintf(fp,"%s",string);

    return;
}
```

I tried dup2 and freopen but they didn't work for me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int file = open("input3.txt", O_APPEND | O_WRONLY);
    if(file < 0) return 1;

    if(dup2(file,1) < 0) return 1;

    printf("Redirect to file!\n");
    printf("enter i : ");
    scanf("%d",&i);



    return 0;
}
```

This dup2() tutorial only print to file.

I also tried tee, but may be it not work because I have to get input from user (if work, it's not "fair" because tee isn't in my program).

I think implement a printf-like will solved problem but I don't know how to convert .*lf
(print out double with user-enter precision)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
void dupPrint(FILE *fp,char *fmt,  ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    char *p, *sval;
    int ival;
    double dval;

    va_start (ap, fmt); //make ap point to 1st unnamed arg
    for(p = fmt; *p; p++)
       {
           if (*p != '%') {
               putchar(*p);
               continue;
           }
           switch (*++p) {
               case 'd':
                   ival = va_arg(ap, int);
                   printf("%d", ival);
                   break;
               case '.*lf' //?????
           }
       }       

}
```

Can anyone suggest a solution for my problem?

Comment: fprintf can print to stdout as well as to files

Comment: You _could_ open a pipe that calls `tee` and print data to that filehandle, but this may not be reliable enough (if this needs to run on systems without `tee`).

Comment: "My C program gets user input by scanf" - you're in for a _world_ of pain :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Fortunately, you don't need to. You just want to use the `v` variants of `printf` and `fprintf` that take a `va_list` instead of your passing arguments directly:

```
void tee(FILE *f, char const *fmt, ...) { 
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vprintf(fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vfprintf(f, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can implement your `dupPrint` function using [vfprintf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/vprintf.html) and [va_list/ va_start / va_end](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/stdarg.h.html).

Answer (score 3):

in the mid-layer:

```
#define DUPPRINT(fp, fmt...) do {printf(fmt);fprintf(fp,fmt);} while(0)
```

in your app code:

```
...
DUPPRINT(fd, "%s:%d\n", val_name, val_v);
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a variadic function and `vprintf`!

```
void dupPrint(FILE *fp,char *fmt,  ...)
{
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vprintf(fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);

    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vfprintf(fp, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
}
```

Optionally, implement `vdupPrint`, have `dupPrint` call `vdupPrint`, and use `va_copy` (if C99 is available) to duplicate the `va_list` instead of the stop-and-restart method I used. (If `va_copy` is not available to you, you'll have to start two separate `va_list`s and pass them both to `vdupPrint`, which is a sub-optimal solution but will work for C89 safely.)