# How to echo text and have output from a command be sent to a file in parallel

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, shell

I would like to echo text and also remotely ping a computer and have the output be sent to a log file.  I also need to do this in parallel but I am having some trouble with how the output is being sent into the log file.

I would like the output to look like:
host | hostTo | result of ping command

but since I have this running as a background process it is outputting:
host hostTo host hostTo rtt
rtt
rtt
etc...

Is there a way to allow this to be a background process but make it so that the echo is part of that process, so the logfile isn't out of order?

here's my script, thanks in advance!

```
 for host in `cat data/ips.txt`; do 
 echo -n "$host ";
 for hostTo in `cat data/ips.txt`; do
 {
     echo -n "$host $hostTo " >> logs/$host.log;
    (ssh -n -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=1 -T username@$host ping -c 10 $hostTo | tail -1 >> logs/$host.log) &

 };
done; 
done
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing to both stdout & a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661070/writing-to-both-stdout-a-file) and [Copy stdout to file without stopping it showing onscreen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356706/copy-stdout-to-file-without-stopping-it-showing-onscreen)

Comment: supposing ips.txt contains one IP address per line, you can avoid a UUOC with `while read -r host ; do ... ; done < data/ips.txt`

Comment: thanks, Ill try that, Mr. Pioulard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to do this with `awk`. What you're basically asking is how to print out the hosts as well as the result at the same time.

ie.  Remove the line with echo and change the following:

`ssh .... ping -c 10 $hostTo | awk -v from=$host -v to=$hostTo 'END {print from, to, $0}' >> logs/${host}.log`

Note that `tail` is effectively being done inside `awk` also. Including shell var inside awk tends to be a PITA, maybe there's an easier way to do it without all the escaping and quotes. [Updated: Assign var in awk]

PS.  The title of your question is a little unclear, it does sounds like you want to pipe your program output to the display and file at the same time.

Comment: `awk -v awkvar=$shellvar 'END {printf awkvar}'`

Comment: I solved this using "'"$host"'" within the awk section, but this seems to be the same thing just a different way. Thanks!

Comment: @Isawpalmetto: It's *much* more readable and maintainable to use variable passing instead of complex quoting.