# How do I save the console output to a textfile in a certain directory?

Tags: java, stream, console

I'd like to keep the console displaying the output but also keep it in a textfile as a log. Is there any way to do this? I tried doing this:

```
PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(locations[0][0] + "-" + locations[0][1] + "-output.txt"));
System.setOut(printStream);
```

But it doesn't display the output in the console anymore and it saves it in the project directory. Is there a way to do both?

Comment: Write a `PrintStream` implementation that logs to two places.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1356706/438992

Comment: @Victor What do you think does he use? `System.setOut(printStream);` looks pretty similar to your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a stream which writes to two destination streams (file and stdio). For example, use [Apache's `TeeOutputStream`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html):

```
// Directory to save log files in
File logDir = new File("/var/log/myapp");
// Name of log file
String logFileName = locations[0][0] + "-" + locations[0][1] + "-output.txt";
// Actual log file
File logFile = new File(logDir, logFileName);

// File stream
OutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(logFile);
// Stdout
OutputStream stdioStream = System.out;
// A stream redirecting output to both supplied streams
OutputStream combinedStream = new TeeOutputStream(stdioStream, fileStream);
// Finally use the resulting stream
System.setOut(new PrintStream(combinedStream));
```

Another alternative (out of the JAVA scope) is to use the *nix `tee` tool:

```
java -cp ... com.package.MyClass | tee /var/log/myapp/mylogfile.txt
```

Comment: Nice suggestions. @RoboticR : Remember that standard output could be redirected from command line, perhaps there is no need to program that

Comment: @Victor Thanks. About stdio redirection: I think I covered that with the `tee` command.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This worked for me. Now is there a way for me to set the file location?

Comment: @RoboticR Of course, will update my answer.