# Example in "Copy STDOUT to file without stopping it showing onscreen" doesn't work

Tags: java

Using example in "Copy STDOUT to file without stopping it showing onscreen", output after a Tee operation is not working as expected.

Studied and copied code from example on stackOverflow.

```
public class TeeStreams extends PrintStream {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("test sysout before");
        System.err.println("test syserr before");

        PrintStream orgSO = System.out;
        PrintStream orgSE = System.err;

        PrintStream logout = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("D:\\TeeStreams.log", false));

        PrintStream teeStdOut = new TeeStreams(System.out, logout);
        PrintStream teeStdErr = new TeeStreams(System.err, logout);

        System.setOut(teeStdOut);
        System.setErr(teeStdErr);

        System.out.println("test sysout inside"); //error here...both copies are in log, no console display
        System.err.println("test syserr inside"); //error here...both copies are in log, no console display

        System.setOut(orgSO);
        System.setErr(orgSE);

        teeStdOut.close();
        teeStdErr.close();

        System.out.println("test sysout after");
        System.err.println("test syserr after");
    }    

    public TeeStreams(PrintStream out1, PrintStream out2) {
        super(out1);
        this.out = out2;
    }

    public void write(byte buf[], int off, int len) {
        try {
            super.write(buf, off, len);
            out.write(buf, off, len);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        //super.close();  // causes NullPointerException
        try {
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

Curiously, output to log is formatted in unexpected manner:

test sysout insidetest sysout inside

test syserr insidetest syserr inside

No output to console while Tee is active....both copies went to log file.  Log file format is unusual.  Why doesn't the log file contain 4 lines instead of 2 (actually 2 text and 2 blank)? The before and after displays work as expected.

I'm running this in NetBeans.....is there a conflict with the way NB's handles the console??

Comment: Where did you copy this code from exactly?

Comment: Not exactly a copy; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356706/copy-stdout-to-file-without-stopping-it-showing-onscreen

Comment: I missed class definition in original code listing.

Answer (score 0):

Found another example on web that solved this.  Replace the above relevant code with these lines;

```
    private PrintStream ps1, ps2;
    public TeeStreams(PrintStream out1, PrintStream out2) {
        super(out1);
        this.out = out2;
        ps1 = out1;
        ps2 = out2;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte buf[], int off, int len) {
        ps1.write(buf, off, len);
        ps2.write(buf, off, len);
    }
```

Comment: Ummm. [Okay](http://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/need-to-write-same-content-to-multiple.html).